# $\rho-3P$ for ultra-relativistic regime in early universe

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-gravity, dark-energy, modified-gravity

I am trying to read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05183v2), in which they try to get dark energy by modifying the EFEs to its unimodular form. As interesting as it may be for someone here, I'm struggling to understand the equation $(12)$ in the paper. Which reads as follows $$\rho-3P\approx\frac{m_t^2T^2}{2\hbar^3},$$ here $m_t$ is the top mass and $T$ is temperature of the universe. The paper claims the relationship should follow from standard thermodynamics. However, I am at a loss in understanding how to arrive at this expression. A derivation or even a hint for how to arrive at a relation like $\rho-3P\approx\frac{m^2T^2}{2\hbar^3}$ up to first order of approximation from standard thermodynamics would be appreciated.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statistical mechanics the energy density and pressure have the following definitions,
$$\rho=g\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}Ef(\vec{x},\vec{p},t)\\
P=g\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}\frac{p^2}{3E}f(\vec{x},\vec{p},t).$$
Here, $g$ is the degeneracy factor and $f(\vec{x},\vec{p},t)$ is the distribution function of particles in phase space and in thermal equilibrium will be equal to either Bose-Einstein or Fermi-Dirac distribution for bosons and fermions respectively,
$$f=\frac{1}{\exp\left[\frac{E}{T}\right]\pm1}.$$
For massless particles, $|\vec{p}|=E$ and therefore $\rho-3P=0$. For ultrarelativistic particles which are in a very high temperature (conditions resembling the early universe) $\frac{m}{T}\ll1$, the distribution fuction still behaves like that of a massless one,
$$f=\frac{1}{\exp\left[\frac{p}{T}\right]\pm1},$$ however, we can obtain the first order correction for massive particles by expanding $E$ for ultrarelativistic particles of small mass,
$$E=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}\approx p(1+\frac{m^2}{2p^2})=p+\frac{m^2}{2p}.$$
The first order correction in energy density is,
$$\rho^{(1)}=\frac{gm^2}{2(2\pi\hbar)^3}\int_0^\infty dp4\pi p^2\frac{\frac{1}{p}}{\exp\left[\frac{p}{T}\right]\pm1}=\frac{gm^2}{4\pi^2\hbar^3}\int_0^\infty dp\frac{p}{\exp\left[\frac{p}{T}\right]\pm1}=\frac{gm^2T^2}{4\pi^2\hbar^3}\int_0^\infty dy\frac{y}{e^y\pm1}\propto m^2T^2.$$
One must perform the zeta function integral to get the correct numerical values. For pressure expand as follows,
$$\frac{p^2}{3E}\approx \frac{p}{3}(1-\frac{m^2}{2p^2}).$$
And similarly one can find the first order correction in pressure which will be of the order of $m^2T^2$. Therefore, for ultrarelativistic massive particles,
$$\rho-3P\approx\mathcal{O}[m^2T^2].$$
I leave it as an exercise to the OP to calculate the correct numerical factors.

**Mathematical aid**

Let,
\begin{align}
    I_n^\pm=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x\pm1}dx.
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}
    I_n^--I_n^+=\int_0^\infty x^n\frac{2}{e^{2x}-1}dx=2^{-n}\int_0^\infty\frac{y^n}{e^y-1}dy=2^{-n}I_n^-.
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
    I_n^+=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)I_n^-.
\end{align}
And,
\begin{align}
    I_n^-=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}dx=\Gamma(n+1)\zeta(n+1).
\end{align}